Ubuntu Server Timeout on "Job dev-disk-by\x2uuid-01AB8EDCE4HE431.device/start running" During Boot
I am experiencing an issue with my Ubuntu Server where the boot process hangs on the following job:
Job dev-disk-by\x2uuid-01AB8EDCE4HE431.device/start running ((elapsed time)s / 1:30)
Eventually, it times out. The system is primarily used for running a Minecraft server.
Here are some details about my setup:

System: HP ProBook 640 G4
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu Server 24.10
Additional Software: Cockpit for management, Plex media server
Storage Configuration: Original 250GB NVMe-SSD (Windows dual boot, but I think that isn't the problem) and an additional 500GB ntfs hard drive is mounted for media files

I suspect the issue is related to the disk not being ready in time during boot, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Here are some steps I've tried without success:
I would appreciate any guidance on:

Diagnosing the root cause of the timeout.
Configuring Ubuntu to ignore the problem.
Alternative solutions, such as changing fstab options or using a different mounting method.

